# How to integrate Sails.js with Drywall

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, drywall

I'm evaluating Sails.js for my next project. I think it is a very well laid out project and the framework for Node that mostly resembles Django, that I'm used to.

One thing that every Django developer is gonna miss from any framework not providing it, is the admin page, a very quick and powerful way to administrate the site as you go, test out things, input the initial data and so on.

I've found out Drywall and it looks amazing. Only, it is a framework by its own. I'd just like to use Sails for the site and have a backend administration page provided by Drywall.

How to integrate the two, or: is there any admin plugin for Sails.js?

Thanks

Comment: Title says "drywell," post and tag says "drywall," which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sails.js Admin Page Scaffolding has been an [open issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/915) for a few months now. I think it may come after [associations](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124) which would make sense - what is User administration if you can't change its Role presented by its label rather than its id.

It shouldn't be too hard since Sails already produce a REST API for each model you set up.

Using Drywall with Sails seems pretty difficult. Sails is DB agnostic while [Drywall wants you to use MongoDB](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall#requirements).

Drywall seems more like a tool to build website where Sails is more like a framework to build api based webapp.

Answer (score 3):

I am the co-creator of [Strapi](http://strapi.io/).

Strapi is a Node.js framework based on [Koa](http://koajs.com). It ships a complete user system management and an auto-generated admin panel.

Feel free to try it and let us know if you have any question.

Pierre

Comment: does it work **with** sails? looks more like an alternative to sails...